# GCVirtualController - change element style and position for thumbsticks

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, gamekit

I am working on a SwiftUI-based application that utilizes [GCVirtualController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamecontroller/gcvirtualcontroller) to provide basic on-screen controls. While getting it set up has been relatively simple, I'm not particularly happy with layout and appearance of the controls themselves -- especially in portrait mode where the layout is completely broken.

Ideally what I'd like to do is to move the thumbsticks closer together and otherwise alter their appearance (such as make them smaller and/or add some more transparency).

Apple has some pretty sparse documentation on GCVirtualController and I don't see many examples of this API's use just looking around on GitHub. What I *can* find is it should be possible to customize the appearance of controller elements via the [ElementConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamecontroller/gcvirtualcontroller/elementconfiguration) object. Among other things, this allows for a UIBezierPath property which seems like exactly what I would need. The problem is if I use code like this:

```swift
virtualController.updateConfiguration(forElement: GCInputLeftThumbstick, configuration: { _ in
  var c = GCVirtualController.ElementConfiguration()
  c.path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
  return c
})
```

It doesn't seem to actually do anything to change the thumbstick appearance at all. (If I change other properties like "`c.isHidden = true`" that does work so I do know *something* is wired up here behind the scenes.)

For the sake of experimentation I tried applying this same code to GCInputButtonA and it did change the *inner*-button appearance -- so that's something, but it's not really what I want either. Maybe I'm just running into some undocumented limitations with this API.

Then there's the other problem -- even if I am able to somehow customize the appearance of the thumbsticks, I still do not see any obvious way to alter their positioning on the screen. This is important because right now GCVirtualController is broken on portrait mode; the left analog thumbstick is completely missing so I'd like to move things closer together while in portrait mode.

Hopefully someone who's more familiar with this may have some ideas what I'm getting wrong here. I'd prefer to not have to use 3rd party virtual controller APIs if possible, but I have a distinct feeling that's the direction I'll need to go.

Comment: I don't use this particularly but the Apple samples and videos might be useful if you haven't tried them https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamecontroller/supporting_game_controllers

Comment: Thanks -- I did watch the videos before but I watched them again and they say pretty plainly that manual placement is not supported (which really stinks). They also say that you should be able to customize elements with UIBezierPath but that doesn't seem to work with analog sticks (which isn't documented anywhere I can find but seems to be the case). It seems like GCVirtualController is pretty inflexible once you want to go beyond the most basic use cases and that's a bummer. I guess I'll need to find something else to meet my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I too am excited! :)
I watched the video and they just outright changed the "method/func/api"
Here is what I came up with and an example.
What I also found out is, I am pretty sure you can put any symbol like say size 500x500, since you need a UIBezierPath, the api just scales the bounds to fit in the button (but you have to center).  Without further a do...

```
let virtualConfiguration = GCVirtualController.Configuration()
virtualConfiguration.elements = [GCInputLeftThumbstick,
                                 GCInputRightThumbstick,
                                 GCInputButtonA,
                                 GCInputButtonB,
                                 GCInputButtonX]

virtualController = GCVirtualController(configuration: virtualConfiguration)
        
virtualController!.updateConfiguration(forElement: GCInputButtonX, configuration: { _ in
  let starPath = GCVirtualController.ElementConfiguration()
    
    let offX = -25.0
    let offY = -26.0
    starPath.path = UIBezierPath()
    starPath.path!.move(to: CGPoint(x: 25+offX, y: 1+offY))
    starPath.path!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 33.82+offX, y: 13.86+offY))
    starPath.path!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 48.78+offX, y: 18.27+offY))
    starPath.path!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 39.27+offX, y: 30.64+offY))
    starPath.path!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 39.69+offX, y: 46.23+offY))
    starPath.path!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 25+offX, y: 41+offY))
    starPath.path!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 10.31+offX, y: 46.23+offY))
    starPath.path!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 10.73+offX, y: 30.64+offY))
    starPath.path!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 1.22+offX, y: 18.27+offY))
    starPath.path!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 16.18+offX, y: 13.86+offY))
    starPath.path!.close()
    UIColor.gray.setFill()
    starPath.path!.fill()

  return starPath
})
            
// Connect to the virtual controller if no physical controllers are available.
if GCController.controllers().isEmpty {
    virtualController?.connect()
}
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the alpha of the GCControllerView by using the keyWindow. GCControllerView is a subclass of UIView.

```
    // make GCControllerView transparent
    
    for TransitionView in UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.subviews ?? [] {
                    
        for DropShadowView in TransitionView.subviews {
                            
            for LayoutContainerView in DropShadowView.subviews {
                                    
                for ContainerView in LayoutContainerView.subviews {
                                        
                    if "\(ContainerView.classForCoder)" == "GCControllerView" {
                        
                        ContainerView.alpha = 0.6
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```